# How to pass collection variable (var result) values from Controller to View in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Ex: Here I can get `count=2` with values in variable result. But how can I display these values using View.
I am getting the error as below:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 
'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType3`2[System.Int32,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[KShoppingCart.Models.Category]'.
```

Answer (score 1):

- The first and preferable option will be to create custom type for
  your ViewModel and pass it to view.
- The second option is to use
  Dynamic model type or pass data through ViewBag.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. declare the model as dynamic in the view, i.e `@model dynamic`
2. create a new typed class, return an object of this class from the controller to the view, and declare this class as the model type in your view

The second option is the usual and best way to do this. The declared class is called "view model", and you should always create view models for all your views.